# Adding 2 numbers in C# Xamarin Button won't Work

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to do a simple addition in C# using Xamarin
the button which is supposed to add the numbers refused to add the numbers and hence would not work in any way

Code looks like this :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    /* Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
     SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);*/

    /*FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
    fab.Click += FabOnClick;*/

    myLabel = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.myLabel);
    myLabel2 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.myLabel2);
    num1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.num1);
    num2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.num2);
    myButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);

    myButton.Click += (o, e) =>
    {

        int number1;
        int number2;
        if (int.TryParse(num1.Text, out number1) && int.TryParse(num2.Text, out number2))
        {
            int result = number1 + number2;
            // dialog.SetMessage(string.Format("Result is given as: " + result));
            Toast.MakeText(this, result, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    };
}
```

Now the trouble / Exception it triggers come from this point :

```
Toast.MakeText(this, result, ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

Which is supposed to show the results, i am quite new to Xamarin. So i appear to be needing help here . Do i `Convert.ToString()`

Comment: `result.ToString()` (or `$"{result}"`)

Comment: what is the specific exception or error message?

Comment: @Jason By passing an `int` for the second param of `MakeText`, it is trying to use the int value as a Resource ID.

Comment: How stupid of me! To String was what i needed. Thank you @SushiHangover

Comment: @SushiHangover **I** know that, but was trying to point ou t to OP the importance of posting exact error messages instead of vague descriptions

Comment: @jason, no vague description. appears u didnt read what i said earlier. U can have your fun now. Sushi has made my day...

Answer (score 0):

> Now the trouble / Exception it triggers come from this point :
>   Toast.MakeText(this, result, ToastLength.Short).Show();

[image]
Let's have a look at the up image,I guess you have found the reason.`Toast.MakeText` second parameter looks like an int type.However when you set a *int* (result) , it occur error.So if checking more carefully,we will find it is a **resId**, a resource id ,and is a string resource id.(*Why not other type resource id,reason in second solution*)

**The Solution one** :

You can set a Sting id , then it can work.

ex:  `Toast.MakeText(this, Resource.String.abc_capital_on, ToastLength.Short).Show();`

From document,this may be the best recommended way by Xamarin Android.

**The Solution two** :

From Google develop [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)),you will find the second parameter is a **CharSequence**(a readable sequence of char values).In a sense, *CharSequence* represents a **string** in Android, but does not include all the cases, the specific difference can see the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html).So if you convert the *int* (result) to *string*. Then it will also work. Here are some methods for reference:

```
string FinalResult = result.ToString();
string FinalResult = Convert.ToString(result);
string FinalResult = string.Format("{0}", result);
string FinalResult = $"{result}";
string FinalResult = "" + result;
string FinalResult = string.Empty + result;
string FinalResult = new StringBuilder().Append(result).ToString();

Toast.MakeText(this, FinalResult, ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

Note: Now maybe you will understand the first soultion why should be a string resource id to set.